# Instance of 'std::out_of_range' with vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

1. Hi, i've been recently working with vector but it seems that when i input "3+2+1" or so, my expected output would be "1+2+3"  console says: " terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' original problem is from: http://www.codeforces.com/problemset/problem/339/A. What's my problem? thks for help!.
2. ```
     #include <bits/stdc++.h>
      using namespace std;

     int main (){


    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
     cin.tie(NULL);


   vector <int> a;
    string str;
   cin>>str;

       for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++){
               if(str[i]!='+')
                 {
                     int c = str[i]-'0';
                     a.push_back(c);
                 }
       }

   sort(a.begin(), a.end());
   cout<<a.at(0);
         for(int j = 1; j < str.size(); j++){

             cout<<'+'<<a.at(j);

       }


       return 0;
      }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the stop condition of the loop to be stopping on the size of the vector and not the string.  So change your last loop to the following

```
for(int j = 1; j < a.size(); j++){
    cout<<'+'<<a.at(j);
}
```

Further if you want to print all the values in the format you specified you would want to do the following

```
assert(!a.empty());
for(int j = 0; j < a.size() - 1; j++){
    cout << a.at(j) << '+';
}
cout << a.back() << endl;
```

---

One last thing about your implementation.  If you are always going to be given a string of the format "a+b+c+d" you do not need a vector to reverse the sequence and print.  You can simply do the following

```
std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end()); // #include <algorithm>
```

And then the string will have the sequence you want.  If you do not want to do it in place and need another container you could do

```
// #include <iterator> and #include <algorithm>
string other_string;
std::copy(str.crbegin(), str.crend(), std::back_inserter(other_string));
```

^ This will copy the string in reversed order to another string object.

Comment: Great, what you said worked perfect, thanks a lot. I hava a question, What's the use of "assert(!a.empty());"

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza If the answer was what you wanted could you accept it also please?  You will have to check the slightly greyed out check mark right next to my answer for that.

Comment: I really appreciate thanks a lot, but can't understand the use of the "assert(!a.empty());"

Comment: assert(!a.empty()) would ensure that a is not empty. 
If a is empty it becomes assert(!(true)) which is assert(false) which fails. assert can be used to make sure the invariants and conditions hold. 
Look here for more : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/

Comment: @Prith Thank you for clarifying that!